# How to set template path in redux framework?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, hook, redux-framework

I need to customize panel templates in my theme, which I use redux. I copied **ReduxCore->templates->panel** folder into **mythemefolder->redux-framework->ReduxCore->templates->panel**.

For some plugins, this overrides the templates from plugin, but not the case here, I found that I need to manually tell redux to look for the templates elsewhere other than default folder inside plugin. but I'm not sure how to do it.

I tried adding **'templates_path' => dirname(__FILE__).'/templates/panel',** inside redux config file, but it just throws an error with **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)**

then I found in redux docx,(https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/advanced/filter-hooks/) that there's another way to put **redux/{opt_name}/panel/templates_path**, but it has no reference how, or where to put this code.

can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.redux.io/guides/advanced/panel-templates.html

```
Redux::setArgs('opt_name', array('templates_path'=> dirname(__FILE__).'/templates/panel/'));
```

That SHOULD do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. right before I see your answer, I tried putting *'templates_path' => dirname(__FILE__).'/templates/panel'* inside already existing **$args** array and it worked. is there any difference with that and the way you suggested? which is better?

Comment: Also, you should say, that this line of code should be added into which file, redux config file or theme's functions.php file. redux framework guidelines are somewhat not very clear sometimes

Comment: With the Redux API it can be loaded anywhere. It just has to "run" before the init hook.